# bash script - executing find command gives no output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I'm a total noob at bash so this is most likely a syntax error, but I could not find anything that worked for my syntax in my searches.

**From terminal**, running
`find . -name "*g*"`
results in

```
./.grepdir.sh.swp  
./grepdir.sh
```

However, running **this bash script** called `grepdir.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
startdir="$1";
pattern="$2";
find_cmd="find $startdir -name \"$pattern\"";
echo "$find_cmd";

cmd="$($find_cmd)";
echo "$cmd";
```

from terminal as `grepdir.sh . "*g*"` results in:

```
[user@pc~/dir]$ grepdir.sh . "*g*"
find . -name "*g*"

[user@pc~/dir]$
```

meaning that cmd must be empty. But from my understanding, the string stored in find_cmd was executed and the output captured to cmd, meaning that it should not be empty. Do I have a misconception, or is my syntax just god-awful?

Thanks

Comment: Using `cmd=$(bash -c "$find_cmd")` seems to fix this. But I don't understand the reason why yours not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your version of the script is that the quotes you add actually become part of the argument to find. So you ask it to search for file names that literally include `"*g*"` with quotes.

If you drop adding the quotes and just say `find_cmd="find $startdir -name $pattern";` then it works for patterns not including special characters. Then I thought maybe this would work:

```
grepdir.sh . \*g\*
```

or even

```
grepdir.sh . \\\*g\\\*
```

but no. These things are always tricky....

Edit: A-ha, this version seems to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
startdir="$1";
pattern="$2";
find_cmd="find $startdir -name $pattern";
echo "$find_cmd";

GLOBIGNORE=$pattern
cmd="$($find_cmd)";
echo "$cmd";
```

Comment: You're not coding in C and therefore no practical reason to be using the `;` metacharacter to end each line.

Comment: Right, I didn't notice that and I just copied the original. But I didn't add a ; to the extra line I added. :-)

Comment: +1. But the real answer is simply [don't put commands and arguments in a variable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: After more thought I thought that the problem was with globbing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this way -->

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$1
file="*$2*"
find $dir -iname $file -print
```

Comment: You should include explanation for your code. Describing how and why this code solves the problem is more useful as it helps the OP and other readers solve this and similar issues themselves.